# Can't close Windows 8.1 apps by dragging from the top of the screen

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I've just set up a new PC for a user in my office, with a brand new Windows 8.1 installation.

He was having a look around on it, and openened up a couple of the fullscreen apps. He gave me a shout as he couldn't close them, so I went through to have a look.

Normally you can left-click at the top of the app and drag it to the bottom of the screen to close it, but for some reason nothing happens when you click and drag.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this too.  I can get it to drag "sometimes" (after 20 tries).  You can of course use the 8.1 title bar's "x" to close it, but there seems to be an issue with the title bar getting in the way of the "drag from the top" functionality.  Weather app does it, among others.